# How to execute a script via a keybinding in Gnu Screen?

Tags: linux, bash, themes, keyboard-shortcuts, gnu-screen

I want to attach a keybinding to call a script in screen.   I have tried "bind ^k /path/to/script" in my .screenrc, reloaded screen and tried C-a-k and C-k and nothing is executed.

The script in question:

```
#!/bin/bash

INDEXFILE="$HOME/bin/screen/themes/theme_index"

# if this is the first time then set
# the index to 0

if [[ ! -e $INDEXFILE ]]
then
  echo 0 > $INDEXFILE
fi

THEMENO=`cat $INDEXFILE`

THEMEMAX=5

if [[ $THEMENO -eq $THEMEMAX ]]
then
  THEMENO=0
else
  THEMENO=`expr $THEMENO + 1`
fi 

echo $THEMENO > $INDEXFILE

THEMEFILE=$HOME/bin/screen/themes/theme${THEMENO}
```

This references to a themeindex file which will contain a number 0-5.  As well as "theme files" which look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# yellow

SESSION=$1

screen -S $SESSION -X caption always "%{= KW}%-w%{= Yk}%n %t%{-}%+w %-="
screen -S $SESSION -X hardstatus alwayslastline "%{= kW} %-= %{= kY}Session: %u%{= kW}%5\` | %{= kY}Host:%{= kW} %H | %{= kY} Uptime:%{= kW} %4\` | %{= kY} MEM:%{= kW} %2\`MB |%{= kY} SW: %{= kW}%3\`MB | %{= kY} DATE:%{= kW} %m/%d/%y %C %A"
```

Essentially allowing me to change the color of the Gnu Screen theme. Different sessions would be a different color to be more immediately identified visually. The script works on it's own if called directly but i would really like it attached to a key binding.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `bind ^k /path/to/script` you should use `bind ^k exec /path/to/script`.

Comment: i did that, changed the binding to a number of letters and all to no avail.   The script still won't execute.  I got it working through a bash alias, but that requires me to be in a local shell for it to work.

Comment: Well, the problem is your script, but that's not what you ask. You asked how to execute an external program through a keybinding and that's what you've got as an answer.